# how to pass custom command line to locust in no-web mode

Tags: java, python, csv, jmeter, locust

I were using jmeter till now but i saw it is taking lots of resources and memory to run,
so now i started reading locust. i am new to locust.
i want to use locust in no-web mode e.g $ locust -f locust_files/my_locust_file.py --no-web -c 1000 -r 100 but same as question asked by someone to pass ${url} and ${host} from command line , i dont want to hard code the URL or you can say header parameter like unique request id and all, i want to pass it from command line, like we can pass in jmeter and we can get it in configuration file using __P() function.
how we can get the same thing in locust, i know the way of using environment variables but i do not want to use this.

Comment: Have you tried using the options available from `--help` -- both `--host` and `--web_host` are already options...

Comment: I want to pass custom command line option irrespective of any option available like we can pass in jmeter and we can get it in configuration file using __P() function.